# Cross-browser CSS Variants in PhpStorm?

Tags: css, phpstorm

I was creating a stylesheet in PhpStorm.

I started with the intent of typing the following:

```
<code>
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
</code>
```

Not sure what I did, but got the following (very helpful):

```
<code>
*{
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
</code>
```

Does anyone know the shortcuts to get all(most) cross-browser variants of a css declaration in PhpStorm?

Comment: jsyk, the `box-sizing` css attribute is supported without prefixes in 96% of browsers, and there is less than 1% that supports only with prefixes: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Comment: What happened is called *[vendor prefixing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)*  - check the [manual](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/CSS+Editor+in+PhpStorm) for how to do this, intentionally.

Answer (score 4):

This is [CSS Vendor Prefixes](http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/vendor-prefixes/) in action. It is done **by Emmet**.

You can see all settings at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet | CSS`.

Corresponding help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/css.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate codes like that (cross-browser codes), you can use from some short codes in PhpStorm. They are so useful and exist for HTML, CSS, JavaScript, SQL, PHP, Angular and so on. 
To see them in your IDE, you can go to **setting** and then in the search box, write: "**Live Templates**" (It's located in the 'Editor' section). In right hand side, you can see all of definitions, also you can define your desire short code to generate code easily in your IDE, e.g if you want to write CSS code like: `border-right: 1px solid #000;` you only need to write `br+` and then press Tab key to complete all of this. It's so useful when you have to write long code and it will save your time a lot.

[image: The image of Live Templates in PhpStorm setting]

In your example above, you only need to write: '**bxz**' and then press **Tab key**, you will see that all of cross-browser codes will generate automatically in your IDE. You can see this in the following images:

[image]

[image]